# alter column size take very long time?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table with 45M rows (45 GB data space and 2GB Index space). I added a new column and it finished instantly.

```
alter table T add C char(25)
```

Then I found the size is too small so I run the following query.

```
alter table T alter column C varchar(2500)
```

And it runs one hour and is still running. sp_whoisactive shows (at the moment, still running)

```
reads: 48,000,000
writes: 5,000,000
physical reads: 3,900,000
```

Shouldn't it be really fast?

Comment: You might get a better answer on [DBA.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: The answer is: Not really, no.

Comment: Adding a column to the end of a table is almost instantaneous, If you change the size of an existing column, the table and potentially indexes, need to be rebuilt

Answer (score 3):

I tested the case. You can do it faster using below steps:

1. Create the same table structure with a different name (call it Tbl2)
2. Alter the column on Tbl2
3. insert data from Tbl1 into Tbl2
4. Drop Tbl1 (the old table)
5. Rename Tbl2 (the new one) to Tbl1

This will give you much better performance.

The reason is, altering the column on table containing data, will take a lot of data transfer and data page alignment. 
Using my solution you just insert data w/o any page reorganization.

<sub>*If a post answers your question, please mark is as answer*</sub>